# Remove row from React table without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React table which has a column containing delete buttons in each row. When a user clicks on the delete button, a modal pops up asking them to confirm deletion. Once user clicks confirm, the modal closes and the row should be deleted from the table.

I am trying to make it so that I don't have to refresh the page to see the updated table and instead see it right away once the confirm button in the modal is clicked and it closes.

Update: I tried the solution from the comments but I'm getting an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'deleteFood' of '_ref' as it is undefined.` How would I fix this error? I'm very new with react so I'd appreciate any help!

This is my index.js file:

```
const DataTable = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const foods = useSelector((state) => state.foodData.foods);

  useEffect(() => {
      if(foods.length === 0) {
          dispatch(fetchFood());
      }
  },[dispatch, foods])

  const mapFoods = foods.map((foods) => ({
    id: foods.foodid,
    food: foods.food
  }));

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {foods.map(food=> {
            return (
              <tr key={food.foodid}>
                <td>{ food.id }</td>
                <td>{ food.food}</td>
                <td><DeleteButton deleteFood={dispatch(deleteFoodById)} id={food.foodid} /></td>
              </tr>
            )
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}
```

My renderDeleteButton (also in index.js):

```
export const DeleteButton = ({deleteFood, id}) => {
  let dialogEl=null;

  const delete_food = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/food/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`);
      deleteFood(id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("delete_food", err.toJSON());
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      // modal
      <dialog ref={(el) => {
        dialogEl = el;
      }}>

        <div role="document">
          <h2>Are you sure you would like to delete this food?</h2>
          <p>This action cannot be undone</p>
          <form method="dialog">
            <div>
              <div>
                <button type="reset" onClick={()=>dialogEl.close()}>Cancel</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button type="del" id="delete_bottom" onClick {()=>delete_question()}>Delete</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </dialog> 

      // delete button
      <button onClick={() =>dialogEl.showModal()} className="delete-btn">
        <span role="img">
          <Icon icon="gg:trash-empty"/>
        </span>
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

My questionnaire.js file:

```
const initialState = {
  foods: []
}

const FoodSlice = createSlice({
  name: "FOOD",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setFood: (state, action) => ({ ...state, foods: action.payload }),
    deleteFoodById: (state, action) => ({ ...state, foods: state.foods.filter(({foodid}) => foodid !== action.payload) })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `window.location.reload(false);` with `dispatch(fetchCriteria());` assuming that the delete_question function is inside a React Functional Component.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a few optimizations you could make to help achieve what you want.

First I think you may be unnecessarily iterating over the criterias array twice - you should be able to just map once while rendering in your JSX return statement.

Second, your renderDeleteButton function looks like it wants to be a react component (it's returning JSX). So you'll want to implement this a little bit differently to allow the component to take in a delete handler and criteria ID as props.

The delete handler should be a dispatch function that updates your state with the new criterias array that does not include the one with that criteria id.

Something like:

```
const DeleteButton = ({id}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let dialogEl=null;

  const delete_question = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/criteria/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`);
      dispatch(deleteCriteriaById(id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("delete_question", err.toJSON());
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      // modal
      <dialog ref={(el) => {
        dialogEl = el;
      }}>

        <div role="document">
          <h2>Are you sure you would like to delete this food?</h2>
          <p>This action cannot be undone</p>
          <form method="dialog">
            <div>
              <div>
                <button type="reset" onClick={()=>dialogEl.close()}>Cancel</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button type="del" id="delete_bottom" onClick={delete_question}>Delete</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </dialog> 

      // delete button
      <button onClick={() =>dialogEl.showModal()} className="delete-btn">
        <span role="img">
          <Icon icon="gg:trash-empty"/>
        </span>
      </button>
    </>
  )
}

const DataTable = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const criterias = useSelector((state) => state.criterias);

  useEffect(() => {
      if(criterias.length === 0) {
          dispatch(fetchCriteria());
      }
  },[dispatch, criterias])

  return (
    <>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {criterias.map(criteria=> {
            return (
              <tr key={criteria.criteriaid}>
                <td>{ criteria.criteriaid }</td>
                <td>{ criteria.criteria }</td>
                <td><DeleteButton id={criteria.criteriaid} /></td>
              </tr>
            )})}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}
```

deleteCriteriaById could probably look something like:

```
deleteCriteriaById: (state, action) => ({...state, 
  criterias: state.criterias.filter(({criteriaid}) => criteriaid !== action.payload)
}),
```

Comment: Hey, no problem! So, to answer your question: yes, the deleteCriteriaById would be a reducer function that returns a new state with a new criterias array minus the one that includes that criteriaid. On a side note though, redux is often a bit overkill for a lot of applications so it might be worth considering another simpler state management solution if you're able. Possibly [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview) might be a reasonable replacement worth exploring?

Comment: Sorry, almost - you just need to check prev.criteria against the action I think

Comment: Also, I updated my answer to include passing in the id to the DeleteButton component (and correctly referencing it there).

Comment: Oh, also I think for redux you want to use action.payload instead of action.id

I can update my answer with this example. Just a min...

Comment: It should be whatever you named the argument in the map callback, so if the map looks like `map(criteria => ` then it would be "criteria". "criterias" is probably the array itself which will return undefined if you access criteriaid as a property on it.

For the destructuring error on _ref though that seems like there might just be a typo somewhere possibly...?

Comment: Is that error showing up in the DeleteButton component or in the parent?

Comment: Found a couple of missing parenthesis and curly braces. I just went ahead and updated my answer with an example where both components are in one file. Hopefully this is more helpful

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need mapCriterias anymore, though if that is an empty array then something else must be going on further up at the state level

Comment: Also, just realized that you should be calling dispatch from the DeleteButton component directly I think - Updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Are you storing criterias directly on your state object or on the questionnaireData property? I think I might have to see more of your implementation to be able to help debug that error. However, I've gone ahead and updated my answer to assume that criterias are not nested when you retrieve them from state in the useSelector hook just in case that helps.